# Who and That : Pronouns or Relative Pronouns

Tags: pronouns, relative-pronouns

I read a submission in a newsletter about grammar. Part of the article discussed the use of **who** and **that**. The reader is told to use **who** as a *pronoun for references to people* and **that** a*s a pronoun for references to inanimate objects*. The author provided examples: “Phoebe is the person **who** lives next door to my daughter.” and “It’s the grocery store **that** is closest to my house.” In closing of this section the author provides the statement, “When did people become objects?”

Aren't **who** and **that** relative pronouns? Also, I don't believe the use of  **who** or **that** are needed in the author’s examples. Composing in plain talk, I would compose the author's examples as: “Phoebe lives next door to my daughter.” and “It’s the grocery store closest to my house.”

Comments please...?

Comment: If you google the uses of *who* and *that* (along with other relative pronouns), you will find that most authorities allow *that* for both people and objects. Who was responsible for your newsletter about grammar?

Comment: My first though was: why not both? Isn't a "relative pronoun" a kind of pronoun, like a "green apple" is a kind of apple? I think it would be easier to answer your question if you explain why you think these are mutually exclusive categories.

Comment: The author of the submitted article is ignorant of the facts about English grammar and has substituted their own facts instead. Ignore them. Either _who_ or _that_ is grammatical as restrictive relative pronouns referring to humans. Strictly speaking, _that_ is a complementizer instead of a pronoun (the same one that appears in _I think that this is correct_), but since it works exactly the same as _who_ it's promoted to associate restrictive relative pronoun in those cases.

Comment: @sumelic Yes, but *is* "that" a relative pronoun? A very large number of grammarians don't think so. They think it is a subordinator which introduces relative clauses. It's the same "that" we find in subordinate content clauses.